# Gulp inject task doesn't work when calling with run-sequence

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject, run-sequence

**Required steps**

1. `clean build` directory.
2. `compile typescript files` then put compiled files in to build directory.
3. `inject compiled files` as script to index.html then put it to build directory.

**Project structure**

```
-- build
-- src
   --app
     --app.ts
     ..
-- index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Gulp tasks**

```
"devDependencies": {
   "del": "^2.2.0",
   "gulp": "^3.9.0",
   "gulp-inject": "^3.0.0",
   "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
   "run-sequence": "^1.1.5"
}

gulp.task('clean', function() {
   return del('build');
});

gulp.task('ts', funtion() {
   var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
   return tsProject.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('inject', funtion() {
   return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src('build/**/*.js', {read: false}), {ignorePath: 'build', relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('build', function() {
   runSequence('clean', 'ts', 'inject');
});
```

**Problem**

When I execute `gulp ts && gulp inject` it works perfectly.

When I excute `gulp build` the `inject` doesn't work with no message print out.

I think there are problems with run-sequence. Could you please help me to figure out the problems and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of digging, I realized that when a task returns an in-appropriate stream, run-sequence stops running with no warning or error.
Hope this will help anyone else who have the same issue.

Comment: Can you please tell what do you mean by in-appropriate stream. Please elaborate your answer with some code.

Comment: @SrikanthReddyKarnati the code is in the question. Try to focus the `clean task`, it doesn't return a proper stream therefore the sequence stop there.